# Restate a logical claim using logical symbols

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Proposition: Strictly between any two distinct rational numbers lies another rational number.

How may I present this statement using logical symbols?

My answer: $\forall x, y \in {\mathbb{Q}}. \space x \neq y \implies \exists z \in {\mathbb{Q}}. \space (x < z < y) \vee (y < z < x)$

I think there is some problem with my statement because I suspect $\forall x, y \in {\mathbb{Q}}. \space x \neq y$ doesn't make much sense.

Could you please shed some light on how I may best write this statement? Thanks.

Comment: I think I am supposed to write $\forall x, y \in {\mathbb{Q}}$ such that $x \neq y$ ... But how may I put "such that" in logical symbols?

Comment: "Such that" is not necessary in the translation; is implicit in the quantifiers. You must only put parentheses in order to disambiguate your formula: $\forall x \forall y (x \ne y) \implies \exists z (...)$ id **different** from $\forall x \forall y [(x \ne y) \implies \exists z (...)]$.

Comment: The only occurrence of "such that" taht you can find is in the formal translation of "the set of $x$ *such that* $\phi(x)$" that becomes : $\{x : \phi(x) \}$; in this case, the ":" translates "such that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to me. When you write
$$
\forall x, y \in \mathbb{Q}, x \neq y \Rightarrow \ldots,
$$
it means that *if* it happens that the $x, y$ you chose are not equal, *then* they must satisfy some property (here the property that another rational number lies between them). If it happens that $x = y$ then the implication is automatically true since the premise is false.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a difference between $$\forall x, y \in \mathbb{Q}, x \neq y \Rightarrow \ldots,$$ and $$\forall x, y \in \mathbb{Q}. x \neq y \Rightarrow \ldots,$$? (The dot and the comma). Or is it simply different notations both mean a condition?

Comment: From what I know the comma should be used in a formal language. I don't think the dot is a conventional symbol in a formal language. But in the end it depends on the conventions you choose.

Comment: BTW, if I had to *define* a symbol meaning "such that", e.g. $|$, I would define it precisely the way you did : $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Q} | x \neq y, \exists z \in \mathbb{Q} \ldots$ iff $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Q}, x \neq y \Rightarrow \exists z \in \mathbb{Q} \ldots$

Comment: The dot are nor longer used (since a century) in place of parentheses; they were introduced as such in *Pricipia Mathematica* of Whitehead and Russell (1910). The comma is not necessary : the "formal way" is $\forall x \forall y (...)$.

Answer (score 2):

You've done fine, except for an important matter of syntax: You need to bracket the entire implication in which $x$ and $y$ appear.

Without doing so, the appearance of $x, y$ in the consequent are *unbound*, i.e., represent free variables, and hence, have no relation to the bound $x, y$.  You also need to bracket the entire disjunction following $\exists z...$, for the same reason, otherwise the second appearance of $z$ is  unbound and has no relation to the quantified variable $z$.

This can be remedied by writing your symbolic statement as follows:

$$\forall x, y \in {\mathbb{Q}} \space \Big(x \neq y \implies \exists z \in {\mathbb{Q}} \space [(x < z < y) \vee (y < z < x)]\Big)$$